# How to copy specific rows (based on a column value) from multiple csv files to a new "masterfile"?

Tags: python, csv, rows

beginner here. Go easy on me.
I have multiple csv files in the sub-folders of a main directory, I am trying to copy specific rows from these csv files into a separate, new, masterfile of sorts based on the values in column 'B'.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(filePath):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".csv"):
                filesList.append(file)
                f = open(os.path.join(root,file), "r")
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
                writer = open("masterfile.csv", 'w')
                writer = csv.writer(writer, delimiter='\t')
                for column in reader:
                    column_list = column[0].split(',')
                    if ("x" in column_list[1] or "y" in column_list[1]) and ("z" not in column_list[1]):
                        writer.writerow(column)
```

I am getting the desired output from the first file in the directory but for some reason, I'm unable to iterate over each of the other 10 files that are remaining. Any tips? Also just pointers for better code are very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't iterate over remaining files? Try printing file names and then check. Also, initialise writer outside the loop.

Comment: Hey, thank you! Moving the writer outside the loop fixed my problem.